# mysql restart won't kill child processes on CentOS

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database running on a CentOS server. I have noticed that, when left to run for several weeks without restarting the service, then when I need to do a restart (`/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`), the service will display "fail" for both stop and start. It will then refuse to start again, unless I `kill -9` the mysqld_safe and mysqld processes.

Why does this happen and what can I do to prevent it?

Using mysql 5.1.66 on Centos 6.3

Comment: What response do you get from the query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'pid_file';`?

Comment: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Answer (score 3):

The script `/etc/init.d/mysqld` is dependent on the presence of the file `mysql.sock`. If that file is missing, run `service mysqld restart` or `service mysqld stop` simply does not work.

Over the years, I have seen many incidents where `mysql.sock` just disappears (going back to MySQL 4.x). See ServerFault Post : [**What should mysqld.sock contain, why don't I have it?**](https://serverfault.com/q/279366/69271). When this happens, you will have to resort to `mysqladmin shutdown`.

If you tried this:

```
mysqladmin -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p shutdown
```

this may fail if it authenticates as `root@localhost`

Instead, shutdown mysql using the TCP/IP protocol

```
mysqladmin -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp -uroot -p shutdown
```

This bypasses checking for the socket file `mysql.sock`.

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT

I have discussed using `mysqladmin shutdown` before

- `Dec 14, 2012` : [Percona-server time out on /etc/init.d/mysql start](https://serverfault.com/a/458195/69271) (ServerFault)
- `May 08, 2012` : [How to properly stop MySQL server on Mac OS X?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17599/how-to-properly-stop-mysql-server-on-mac-os-x/17602#17602)
- `Feb 06, 2012` : [MySQL Database and Table Loss](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/mysql-database-and-table-loss/12366#12366)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to wait for a while so I can try this (freshly restarted instances don't have a problem), I'll post back or accept then.

Comment: +1 this is were I was going asking for the location of the pid file but I'll bet you're spot on in pointing to the socket file.  The file is probably getting removed by `tmpwatch` http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/tmpwatch8.html which may possibly be configured inside /etc/cron.daily on CentOS.