# DB Restart Taking too long, site is down

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, process, shutdown

I tried to restart MySQL through WHM and now its taking way too long to restart, the progress bar is still showing.

What can I do?

I can still access the server via SSH but I cannot connect to MySQL. This is urgent as my online store is now down.

Will restarting the HTTP Server (Apache) help?

Comment: Quick Question: Is this Linux ??? What version of MySQL ???

Comment: Apache should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing any additional information, here is my best guess why MySQL is trying to shutdown for a long time: I suspect mysqld no longer has a socket file.

About 1.5 years ago, I answered [mysql restart issue after move database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106813/mysql-restart-issue-after-move-database/106816#106816). I learned that mysqld depends on the presence of a socket file. If there is no socket, mysqld just draws lots of dots on the screen and then gives up.

In that old post, I wrote three instructions

- kill mysqld_safe
- kill mysqld
- start mysqld

Please go do this now ...

I have discussed MySQL behavior with the socket file (or lack of it) 4 years ago (See my older post [mysql restart won't kill child processes on CentOS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35647/mysql-restart-wont-kill-child-processes-on-centos/35679#35679))

Comment: Depending on what exactly led to MySQL being restarted, and how it was restarted, it may  be running through a lengthy InnoDB recovery.

Comment: Thanks this worked! i first did `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop` then i ran `killall mysqld mysqld_safe` and finally `service mysql start`

Comment: In my case the DB server memory got full. Freeup some memory and try `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop` and then do  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`